# clang++ does not respect -isystem flag, different behavior from g++

Tags: c++, macos, clang++, include-path

On my macOS system, I have the following installed:

- Protobuf 3.14.0 via `brew install protobuf@3.14`
- g++ 10.2.0_4 via `brew install gcc@10`
- clang++ 1200.0.32.29 via XCode

When I check out Google's Protobuf repo and build a file using `clang++`, it seems to ignore the `-isystem` flag that I pass:

```sh
git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git && cd protobuf && git checkout 326ea555b
clang++ -std=c++17 -isystem src -c src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc
```

This gives an error:

```
src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc:56:19: error: return type of out-of-line definition of 'google::protobuf::internal::AnyMetadata::InternalPackFrom' differs from that in the declaration
bool AnyMetadata::InternalPackFrom(const MessageLite& message,
~~~~              ^
/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.h:108:8: note: previous declaration is here
  void InternalPackFrom(const MessageLite& message,
  ~~~~ ^
1 error generated.
```

This happens because [`#include <google/protobuf/any.h>`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/326ea555ba6677b82c5ec072aab16c7c685dd51c/src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc#L31) finds the file `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.h`. I would expect it to find the file [`src/google/protobuf/any.h`](https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf/blob/326ea555ba6677b82c5ec072aab16c7c685dd51c/src/google/protobuf/any.h), because that file exists and I passed `-isystem src`. The signature of the private function `InternalPackFrom` has changed since version 3.14.0, hence the error.

Also, when I try replacing `clang++` with `g++-10`, I get a successful build. (I was under the impression that Clang strives for flag-for-flag compatibility with GCC):

```sh
git clone https://github.com/protocolbuffers/protobuf.git && cd protobuf && git checkout 326ea555b
g++-10 -std=c++17 -isystem src -c src/google/protobuf/any_lite.cc
```

Why does `clang++` ignore the `-isystem` flag here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Combining answers/comments from [Anton Malyshev](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4117097/anton-malyshev) and [Ave Milia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10986054/ave-milia), the apparent reason is that Apple's custom `clang++` version (installed when you install XCode) always inserts `/usr/local/include` at the start of the system include path list, above any other entries, including `-isystem` options passed on the command line. (This is probably a bug). You can confirm this by running

```
clang++ -isystem /tmp -Wp,-v -E -
```

and noting the lines

```
#include <...> search starts here:
 /usr/local/include
 /tmp
```

in the output.

Neither upstream `clang++` nor `g++` have this behavior, so it is a quirk of Apple's build.

To *fix* this problem, you can install `llvm` with Homebrew:

```
brew install llvm
```

and then put Homebrew's `clang++` on your path by following the instructions output by

```
brew link llvm
```

Answer (score 3):

That's not because of `-isystem src`. The problem happens because clang++ contains the path `/usr/local/include` in its list of standard include directories, and g++ doesn't.

You can check the list of standard include directories with the following commands:

`clang++ -nostdlib -Wp,-v -E -`

`g++-10 -Wp,-v -E -`

To avoid including `/usr/local/include/google/protobuf/any.h` by clang++ you can either remove the file or use `-nostdinc` and `-nostdinc++` flags and pass old the include directories manually.

Comment: /usr/local/include shouldn't be a problem. If you run the above clang command with -isystem <existing_directory>, you will see that it is earlier in the queue than default includes.

Comment: I verified that the problem is `/usr/local/include` on my machine with exactly the same clang++ version. I don't have the file in `/usr/local/include` and the any_lite.cc compiles successfully for me.

Comment: Thanks, this is helpful! I see the same difference on my system, Clang has /usr/local/include and GCC doesn't. One thing still isn't clear though: Clang doesn't seem to follow the precedence that GCC defines for -isystem vs "standard system directories". IIUC the -isystem should take priority over any default system directories. https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Directory-Options.html

Comment: @AveMilia when I run `clang++ -isystem src -Wp,-v -E -` I see that `/usr/local/include` appears above `src`, so that seems to contradict your comment. https://gist.github.com/kerrickstaley/34fab4f49b8bc264332fb3dd055a5b68

Comment: @KerrickStaley oh, I guess this is just another AppleClang stupidity... But glad we figured it out. On Linux it behaves correctly: https://gist.github.com/avemilia/8ad0a657585f33d7c92d191f8b36e9d8 . I think you can get normal clang on apple via homebrew.